# Powershell: How do I shift a date (format: yyyymmdd) from any position in the file name to end of the file name?

Tags: powershell, regex, find-and-replace, batch-rename

Currently im using

```
dir | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace "",""}
```

to rename files in a directory. The file names vary and need to be unified.

Examples for file names:

1. 20211112_CLAM_30001_Important information on xyz_DK
2. CLAM_DK_20201002_30001_Protocol for PA01 - email
3. DK_30001_Update on customer increase_signed_20220102

Unified format:

CLAM_30001_Arbitrary text_yyyymmdd

There is a date as an 8 digit no. at an arbitrary position in the file name. The date needs to be the very end of the file name. How can I move it to the end?
(Perhaps REGEX?)

Comment: Id usually use a regular expression with 3 capture groups; everything before the date, the date, and everything after the date. then I'd use an replace expression like $0$2$1 to combine what is before and after the date, and drop the date at the end.

Comment: please add a few sample file names to your Question for folks to work with. _concrete_ is easier to tinker with than _abstract_. [*grin*]

Comment: I added some sample file names. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: if you use `$_.name -match '(19|20\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})'` or another regex of your choice - you will have the complete date in `$Matches[0]` and you can put it wherever you want

Comment: @schwadinho - thank you for the added info. [*grin*] ///// now ... do you really want to combine those 3 input file names into one file name? if not ... please show what you want each to end up with. **_exactly_** what you want each of those demo file names to become.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```ps
gci | Where { $_.Name -Match '\d{8}'} | ForEach {
        if ($_.Name -Match '^(\d{8})_(.+)$') { 
            Rename-Item $_ ( $_.Name -Replace  '^(\d{8})_(.+)$','$2_$1' ) }
        elseif ($_.Name -Match '^(.+_)(\d{8})_(.+)$') { 
            Rename-Item $_ ( $_.Name -Replace '^(.+_)(\d{8})_(.+)$', '$1$3_$2' ) }
    }
```

The code checks where the 8 digits are found in the filename (beginning or other) and rename the files accordingly. No need to check if the 8 digits are at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without `ForEach-Object` using a scriptblock for parameter `-NewName` in which you simply move the captured 8 digits result from the `Where-Object` clause towards the end of the file's BaseName.
Then trim off any leading or trailing underscores and make sure there will be no doubled-up underscores in the new name. Finally append the file's extension (if any).

If a file already had the desired name format, it will not be renamed (a no-op)

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'X:\ThePath' -File | Where-Object { $_.BaseName -match '(\d{8})' } | 
Rename-Item -NewName { (('{0}_{1}' -f ($_.BaseName -replace $matches[1] ), $matches[1]).Trim("_") -replace '_+', '_') + $_.Extension }
```